# Grub error no such partition Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2

My Ubuntu crashed for some reason and when it restarted, it showed this

```
Error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode
Grub rescue>
```

When I do `ls` it only returns

```
(hd0)
```

I tried doing from `ls (hd0,0)` to `ls (hd0,gpt9)` and it always shows

```
Error: no such partition.
```

Even some commands don't seem to work like `boot` it shows

```
unknown command 'boot'
```

When I do `set` it returns

```
cmdpath=(hd0)
prefix=(hd0,gpt3)/boot/grub
root=hd0,gpt3
```

I have no idea what I'm doing, I'm just following some tutorials online and nothing worked. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to reinstall the Linux distribution again.

Make a backup of all your files. You can download an official Ubuntu iso image from this website:

https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

You will need to burn the ISO image onto a flash drive to make it bootable. Personally, I really like BalenaEtcher. You can download it from here:

https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Have a nice day!

Comment: How can I make a backup for the files?

Comment: You can use Clonezilla to be able to make a backup of all the files you need. Here you have the link:

https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php

Comment: I can't use that software since I can't access or even know where my files are, I don't understand! How does it work

Comment: So what I suggest is that you buy a SATA interface on amazon, connect it to your hard drive and when you connect it to a working computer, you take all the data you need from it.

Once that is done, you can reinstall the operating system again.

Here's the device I'm referring to:

https://www.amazon.es/ELUTENG-Pulgadas-Adapter-Compatible-Transcend/dp/B07H7BKN2L/ref=zg_bs_937848031_sccl_3/259-0771599-1561209?psc=1

Comment: @James Gates - to retrieve your data - best option is likely to be to use a live usb session. Use your installation usb media, boot the computer into the usb (you may need to change boot order in bios), select ‘try Ubuntu’ instead of installing. In the live session, you can (hopefully) mount the partition with your files, then copy them to another place (probably best to use another usb drive).